# Classification - get some label value to check how close to another class (Python)

Tags: python, classification, naive-bayes-classifier, python-3.x, text-classification

I am doing text classification in python with 3 alghoritms: kNN, Naive Bayes and SVM. I have 3 classes - easy, medium and hard. The accuracy is quite fine. Is there a way to check for new text its exact value? After label encoding 0 is easy, 1 is medium and 2 is hard. So base on new text for example it is classified as medium but I want to know how close it was to easy/hard. Some of my code snippets:

```
Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = model_selection.train_test_split(
    df['tokens'], df['class'], test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

Encoder = LabelEncoder()
Train_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y)
Test_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y)

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=35)
Tfidf_vect.fit([' '.join(arr) for arr in df['tokens']])
Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform([' '.join(arr) for arr in Train_X])
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform([' '.join(arr) for arr in Test_X])
Naive = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
Naive.fit(Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y)
predictions_NB = Naive.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)
print(round(accuracy_score(predictions_NB, Test_Y)*100, 2))
```

Now when I use Naive.predict() I get 0, 1 or 2. Is there a way to get the EXACT value for example 0,5897237489 which is 1 but I see that it is closer to 0 than 2

If it is not possible with NB, I used SVM and kNN as well:

```
SVM = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', degree=3, gamma='auto')
SVM.fit(Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y)
predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)
print(round(accuracy_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y)*100, 2))


KNN = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
KNN.fit(Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y)
predictions_KNN = KNN.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)
print(round(accuracy_score(predictions_KNN, Test_Y)*100, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Naive Bayes is a classification algorithm that outputs the probability of an input belonging to a class. So you cannot use Naive Bayes to achieve what you want. To get 'in-between' values you need to use a regression algorithm instead. I'm not sure what library you're using, but try to use regression versions Knn and SVM models instead.

Comment: I used both kNN and SVM. How to do it with these algoritms? See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

With Naive Bayes you can predict the probability of a text to belong to each class using the `predict_proba` method. Using this method you'll get a vector of probabilities. For example, if you get `[0.1, 0.5, 0.4]` you know your prediction is the second class, but you'll also know your prediction is closer to the third class than to the first class.

Answer (score 0):

In scikit-learn, the [predict_proba(X)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba) method returns an array of class probability estimates for the data X.